# I'm having an error while typing php artisan migrate

Tags: php, database, laravel, database-connection

when typing the command php artisan migrate, it is giving me an error:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException : SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown 
database 'proj' (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where 
table_schema = proj and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE 
TABLE')
```

Although, i edited the `.env` file and i had created the database `proj` and restart the cmd and also i tried

```
php artisan config:cache
```

and similar commands but still not working

[view error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BnAhB.png)

[phpmyadmin view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4SkQE.png)

[.env file view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X29th.png)

Comment: Please check if you have any database in your mysql server named "proj"?

Comment: i checked it is found and i and see it between the databases in phpmyadmin

Comment: Please check if you can login to the database using a mysql client like toad or workbench with the same credentials that you have given in .env file. I think the database is not created. can you share your .env file and your phpmyadmin screenshot ?

Comment: i added the screenshots to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means that you don't have this database created. First create the database and after run: `php artisan migrate:fresh` to create the tables.

By the screenshots you have uploaded, you have many servers. Check the port of the server `mysql` and change the port on the .env file. This will work.

Comment: i created it, it is found and i and see it between the databases in phpmyadmin

Comment: Do you see information_schema database in phpmyadmin?

Comment: gotcha. In your phpmyadmin, above tables, you have ```current server: mysql```, whats the other options? Seems that you have multiple server... In that case .env file is wrong since the host is localhost there. Change accordingly.

Comment: the other server is MariaDB, what should the host be then?

Comment: create ur database "proj" in mariadb. then run php artisan migrate.

Comment: well, you certainly can't have 2 servers running in the same port, so, check the port that server ```mysql``` is using and setup env file. Discard mariadb for now, because the table proj isnt there.

Answer (score 0):

Open the .env file and edit:

> **DB_CONNECTION**=mysql
>
> **DB_HOST**=127.0.0.1
>
> **DB_PORT**=3306
>
> **DB_DATABASE**= // db Name
>
> **DB_USERNAME**= // db Username
>
> **DB_PASSWORD**= // db Password

Run below commands:

```
php artisan config:cache

php artisan migrate
```

I hope this will help you

Comment: the problem is that he ave many servers and the server port isn't the default.